# How to fetch data from server in the form of array list in desc order in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I'm new to android and making an app in which i need to fetch data from server database. I'm able to fetch the data in simple way but, i want to Fetch the all data  with respect to column "KEY_SCORE" in desc order and setting testID=1 and so on. I tried a lot but didn't succeed. Please someone help me in this.

Here is My DataBase code

```
  package com.education.dBase;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import android.content.ContentValues;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.util.Log;

  import com.education.mobiCoachAllen.NotificationListItem;

  public class ToppersTable extends BaseTable {
  public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_USERID = "userid";
  public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
  public static final String KEY_COUNTER = "timecounter";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "fullname";
  public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "quiz_toppers";

  public static final  String TABLE_CREATE_TOPPERS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME2 + " (" + KEY_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_USERID + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_COUNTER + " TEXT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_SCORE
        + " TEXT);";

  String getTableName() {
    return TABLE_NAME2;
  }

  public ToppersTable(DbHelper dbHelper) {
    super(dbHelper);

  }

  public long insert(String userid, String counter, String name, String score) {

    log("insert answer : " + score);
    long rowid_attribute;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_USERID, userid);
    values.put(KEY_COUNTER, counter);
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
    rowid_attribute = super.insert(values);
    return rowid_attribute;
}

public ArrayList<NotificationListItem> getAllList(
        ArrayList<NotificationListItem> privateArrayList) {

    privateArrayList.clear();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(getTableName(), null, null, null, null, null, null);
    log("getAlllist() cursor : " + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor != null) {
        log("getAlllist() cursor not null ");

        // log(" getAllAlarms() cursor size =" + cursor.getCount());

        int index = 0;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (index < cursor.getCount()) {

            NotificationListItem item = new NotificationListItem();

            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToppersTable.KEY_USERID);
            int scoreIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToppersTable.KEY_SCORE);
            int idCounter = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToppersTable.KEY_COUNTER);
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToppersTable.KEY_NAME);

            item.name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            item.testID = cursor.getString(idIndex);
            item.cmark = cursor.getString(scoreIndex);
            item.time = cursor.getString(idCounter);
            index++;
            privateArrayList.add(item);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        log(" query(): cursor closing");
        cursor.close();

        db.close();
        db = null;
    }

    return privateArrayList;
}

public void deleteitem(int Id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String WHERE = KEY_ID + "=" + Id;
    db.delete(getTableName(), WHERE, null);

    db.close();
}

public void deleteDateitem(String date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    /*
     * String WHERE = KEY_NAME + "=" + date; db.delete(getTableName(),
     * WHERE, null);
     */
    db.delete(getTableName(), KEY_SCORE + "=?", new String[] { date });
    Log.e("Record Deleted", "" + date);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteAll() {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, null, null);
    // db.execSQL("delete * from"+ TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME2);
    db.close();
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public String getSinlgeEntry(String qid) {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME2, null, "qid =?", new String[] { qid },
            null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
    } else {

        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String userId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE));
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return userId;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know about SQL using Order?

Comment: yes...................

Comment: then use RawQuery and use SQL it will automatically list in order